# Snowflake / Snowpark compilation error, column alias on join - invalid identifier

Tags: python, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on a Snowpark worksheet, here is the sample code:

```
source_df = session.table("source")
stg_df = session.table("other_source")

df = (source_df.join(stg_df, source_df.id==stg_df.id, "left")
                 .select("stuff here")
         )
```

I can return and view df, based on the show(), and `print(df.columns)` shows all the column names as uppercase.

The problem comes when I try to join `df` with `stg_df` as the next step:

```
 df2 = (stg_df.join(df, stg_df.id==df.id, "left")
                   .select(stg_df.id.alias("id"))
                   .filter("stuff here")
                )
```

It fails when creating `df2`

Error in Query History:

```
SELECT  *  FROM (( SELECT NULL :: BIGINT AS "l_h6oy_ID", NULL :: DOUBLE AS "l_h6oy_TOTAL_REVENUE", NULL :: TIMESTAMP AS "MODIFIED") AS SNOWPARK_LEFT LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT NULL :: BIGINT AS "r_g5n4_ID", NULL :: DOUBLE AS "r_g5n4_TOTAL_REVENUE") AS SNOWPARK_RIGHT ON ("ID" = "r_g5n4_ID"))

# SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 821 invalid identifier 'ID'
```

It seems the problem is with this part `stg_df.id==df.id`. If I rename either dataframe's ID column name then it works. But how come I do not face this issue in the first join?

Comment: weird, if it is case related, I would expect this error if you have the column names in lowercase. Just out of curiosity, can you try to make it like ```.select(stg_df.id.alias('"id"'))``` ? Unless the name of the column is completely different

Comment: I've tried that, but it seems the problem is with this part `stg_df.id==df.id`. 

If I rename either dataframe's ID column name then it works. But how come I do not face this issue in the first join?

Comment: Also if I remove the select and just do a join, I get an ambiguous error

` df2 = (stg_df.join(df, stg_df.id==df.id, "left")`

"snowflake.snowpark.exceptions.SnowparkSQLAmbiguousJoinException: 1303): The reference to the column 'ID' is ambiguous. The column is present in both DataFrames used in the join."

Comment: first join creates a dataframe assigning random aliases for your ID columns (both). (The same behavior should be seen when running a left join in sql). Your second join tries to find ID column which does note exist in the df generated by the first join

Comment: @aek Yes, so I renamed it (withColumnRenamed), and was able to join. It is confusing at first, because when I used df.show(), the column names appear normally without random alias